# form.has_errors tag not working

Tags: python, django

Im using Django 1.2.3. I have login functionality in my site using `django.contrib.auth.views.login`. The user is able to login after entering correct username and password. But, `form.has_errors` is not working i.e. if the login credentials entered are incorrect i dont see the error message. My login.html in templates/registration is as follows :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>User Login</h1>
        {% if form.has_errors %}
            <p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
        {% endif %}
        <form method="post" action=".">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <p><label for="id_username">Username:</label> {{ form.username }}</p>
            <p><label for="id_password">Password:</label> {{ form.password }}</p>
            <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/" />
            <input type="submit" value="login" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any way to fix this problem?

Please Help
Thank You.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `Form` object does have an `errors` attribute, read [the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors) for more information:

```
{% if form.errors %}
    <p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Apparently `has_errors` was valid in Django 0.95 but not from at least 1.0 upwards (as it was replaced with `errors`). [[reference](http://django-project.blogspot.com/2008/12/errors-and-haserrors.html)]

Comment: +1, for more detail this change has been done in django 1.0 check this link for more info : http://django-project.blogspot.com/2008/12/errors-and-haserrors.html

Comment: @singularity I found that also, the Django docs only go back as far as 1.0, so I cannot verify that.

Comment: @Marcus Whybrow: Maybe i can help with that :) , with some url manipulation :) here is the doc for django 0.96 : http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/0.96/.

Comment: `has_errors` appears once on [/documentation/0.96/forms/](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/0.96/forms/)

Comment: @Marcus Whybrow: Yes the change wasn't explicitly documented in the official documentation i also looked to the __what's new with django 1.0__ part and i didn't see it also !!!

Comment: @singularity I guess documentation was poor back then, in the pre 1.0 days.