# Django - using generic login view not working

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-generic-views

EDIT: the view now does log me in when I enter a correct username and password, but doesn't return any errors when I enter incorrect username and passwords.
I am using the generic login view provided by Django. This is my login.html template:

```
<body>
    <h1>User Login</h1>

    {% if form.has_errors %}
        <p>Your username and password did not match. 
        Please try again.</p>
    {% else %}
        <form method="post" action=" . ">{% csrf_token %}
            <p><label for="id_username">Username:</label>
            {{ form.username }}</p>

            <p><label for="id_password">Password:</label>
            {{ form.password }}</p>

            <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/" />
            <input type="submit" value="login" />
        </form>
    {% endif %}
</body>
```

Now, I am following the tutorial in the book called "Pact Publishing. Learning Website Development with Django". The view never returns

```
form.has_errors
```

even though I purposely submit an incorrect username and password. It just keeps returning me to the same page after I click submit. Also, according to the HTML book I read, it said that the 'action' attribute in the form is the URL of the page on the server that will retrieve the information. Is that why it isn't working? Because my

```
action=" . "
```

?

EDIT: the view is the generic login view:

```
@sensitive_post_parameters()
@csrf_protect
@never_cache
def login(request, template_name='registration/login.html',
          redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME,
          authentication_form=AuthenticationForm,
          current_app=None, extra_context=None):
    """
    Displays the login form and handles the login action.
    """
    redirect_to = request.REQUEST.get(redirect_field_name, '')
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = authentication_form(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            # Ensure the user-originating redirection url is safe.
            if not is_safe_url(url=redirect_to, host=request.get_host()):
                redirect_to = resolve_url(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)

            # Okay, security check complete. Log the user in.
            auth_login(request, form.get_user())

            if request.session.test_cookie_worked():
                request.session.delete_test_cookie()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)
    else:
        form = authentication_form(request)

    request.session.set_test_cookie()

    current_site = get_current_site(request)

    context = {
        'form': form,
        redirect_field_name: redirect_to,
        'site': current_site,
        'site_name': current_site.name,
    }
    if extra_context is not None:
       context.update(extra_context)
    return TemplateResponse(request, template_name, context,
                            current_app=current_app)
```

and my urls.py is just

```
url(r'^$', main_page),
url(r'^user/(\w+)/$', user_page), 
url(r'^login/$', login),
```

Comment: `action` should indeed point the URL that you defined in your `urls.py` to recieve this form. For a more complete answer we would need to see the view code.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GDtHrsq271o&list=PL385A53B00B8B158E&index=29

Comment: @YerayDiazDiaz hm okay I edited my post and gave urls.py and the login view. So should I try to change my action to action='127.0.0.1/login/'?

Comment: @user2719875 - There is no need to change action. You need to set `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` field in settings.py file.

Comment: @python-coder I made LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '' because I want to redirect it to the main page. It still never returns any error message even when I purposely put in incorrect username and passwords and does nothing when I put in the correct username and password. It just returns to the login page in both situations. Any idea why?

Comment: See my answer. If you still faces the same problem, notify me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, found the answer over here:
[form.has_errors tag not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614769/form-has-errors-tag-not-working)

```
form.has_errors
```

was replaced with

```
form.errors
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

**Login.Html**

```
    <form action ="." method = POST>
        {% csrf_token %}    
        {{ form.as_p }}

        <input type = "submit" value = "login" class="btn">

    </form>
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout
from django.conf.urls import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'login/',login,kwargs = {'template_name' : 'templates/auth/login.html'},
    url(r'logout', logout,kwargs = {'template_name' : 'templates/auth/logout.html'}),
)
```

**settings.py**

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL  = '/dashboard'
LOGIN_URL           = '/login/'
```

Comment: hm, it still gives the same 'error'. It's not really returning an error, it just keeps returning me back to 127.0.0.1/login regardless of what I do.

Comment: Have you created any user? What happens when you try to log into the django-admin(if you have enabled it)?

Comment: a user has been created, and yup I enabled the admin interface. There is 1 user. But even if there wasn't, it should still say "Your username and password did not match. 
        Please try again." if I enter in an incorrect username and password right? And by the way, I just use the generic login view but now that I am reading over it, in which lines does it take the username and password and verify that the username and password match the username and password in the database?

Comment: Are you able to log into django-admin?

Comment: yup i'm able to log into django-admin. And by the way, I just use the generic login view but now that I am reading over it, in which lines does it take the username and password and verify that the username and password match the username and password in the database? Because when I go to the admin interface and look at the existing user, there is the users username and email address given, the first and last name of the username is blank but there is no password field.

Comment: okay wait, after logging into the admin interface, the view does log me in when I enter a correct username and password, but doesn't return any errors when I enter incorrect username and passwords.

Comment: The password's field is in the `auth_user` table.